# How to know the currently focused item position in ListView or GridView?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, focus, android-navigation

I am developing android app for android currently with Android4.2.2(API 19) and in feature it will support for Android 5.0 also.

My application has both **Grid View and List View** .I need to find the **current focused item of the Grid View/List View** because i need to show that item with zoom-out.

**Note:We are navigating List View/Grid View using D-pad.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this by using [getSelectedItemPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition())();

Answer (score 1):

You can use setOnFocusChangeListener() to know the focused item.

```
listView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                //Your logic
            }
             //or
            if(v.isFocused()){
               //
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here how to get the currently focused item position? I need currently focused item position.

Comment: what you are going to do with position?

Comment: i want to add some animation while navigating the items in menu.Like showing zoom-out ....

Comment: I think you can achieve those thing inside the condition. if focus true do the animation else your wish